# Send data to Firebase Realtime Database without deleting existing data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase Storage to store an image file and when I tried to send it to the Realtime Database the data rewrote the whole data so my existing data is gone and replaced by just the image URL data. How do I send it without deleting my existing data?

This is my code:

```
public class Utama extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private Button uploadBTN;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView namapengguna, emailpengguna;
    private View headerView;


    private FirebaseUser user;
    private DatabaseReference root;
    private StorageReference reference;
    private Uri imageUri;


    private String userID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_utama);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        uploadBTN = findViewById(R.id.upload_btn);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        namapengguna = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.namalengkap);
        emailpengguna = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.emailpengguna);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 2);

            }
        });

        uploadBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (imageUri != null) {
                    uploadToFirebase(imageUri);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Utama.this, "Please Select Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        userID = user.getUid();

        final TextView fullNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fullName);
        final TextView emailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailaddress);

        root.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                User userProfile = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                if (userProfile != null) {
                    String fullName = userProfile.fullname;
                    String email = userProfile.email;

                    fullNameTextView.setText(fullName);
                    namapengguna.setText(fullName);
                    emailTextView.setText(email);
                    emailpengguna.setText(email);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Utama.this, "Terjadi Kesalahan Pada Database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }

    private void uploadToFirebase(Uri uri) {
        StorageReference fileRef = reference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(uri));
        fileRef.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());
                final Uri downloadUri = uriTask.getResult();

                if (uriTask.isSuccessful()){
                    HashMap<String,Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                    result.put(userID,downloadUri.toString());

                    root.child(userID).updateChildren(result).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility((View.INVISIBLE));
                            Toast.makeText(Utama.this, "Your Profile succesfully changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_photo);
                        }
                    })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    Toast.makeText(Utama.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                }
//                fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
//                        Model model = new Model(uri.toString());
//                        String modelId = root.push().getKey();
////                        root.child(userID).child(modelId).setValue(model);
//                        root.child(userID).child(modelId).setValue(model);
//                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//                        Toast.makeText(Utama.this, "Upload Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_photo);
//                    }
//                });
            }
        })
//                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
//            @Override
//            public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
//                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            }
//        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(Utama.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri mUri) {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(mUri));
    }


    public void ClickMenu(View view) {
        Dashboard.openDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }

    public void ClickLogo(View view) {
        Dashboard.closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }

    public void ClickHome(View view) {
        Dashboard.redirectActivity(this, Dashboard.class);
    }

    public void ClickUtama(View view) {
        recreate();
    }

    public void ClickAboutUs(View view) {
        Dashboard.redirectActivity(this, AboutUs.class);
    }

    public void ClickLogout(View view) {
        logout (this);
    }

    private void redirectActivity(Activity activity, Class aClass) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, aClass);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static void logout(Activity activity) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setTitle("Logout");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure want to logout?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                activity.finishAffinity();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Dashboard.closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is for `Model`:

```
public class Model {

    private  String imageUrl;
    public String fullname, email;

    public Model (){

    }

    public Model(String imageUrl){
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;

    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

[here is the problem how can I rename the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYY2g.jpg)

Comment: Please share the code where you are adding data to the database.

Comment: i though its already on the code

Comment: i just edited the code

Comment: Have you tried to use updateChildren() method instead of using setValue()? As you only need to update the URL, right?

Comment: i already tried it doesnt work

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with updateChildren()?

Comment: You should edit your question, there's a button under your question called "Edit".

Comment: i already edited the code, and i found new issue. The saved imageUri saved as userID . which is the same with parent.

Comment: how can rename it, i tried to use Model but it needs to create method

Comment: What exactly would you like to rename?

Comment: the data in firebase saved in child named same with the userID, i would like to rename it with image

Comment: Can you please provide a concrete example?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/162O-swlorUb9hIAcjYQdWEvRKgd8sw24/view?usp=sharing seems easier when you see it

Comment: Please add it to your question and not as an external link.

Comment: okay i already added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here is the problem how can I rename the image

There is no need to rename the image. You can update it correctly even from the beginning. When you add data to Firebase, your structure looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- Users
        |
        --- Pp3Cc... smV2
              |
              --- email: "test@gmail.com"
              |
              --- fullname: "Test"
```

Now, to add a new property within the UID's node called "imageUrl", that can hold the actual URL of the photo, please change the following line of code:

```
result.put(userID,downloadUri.toString());
```

To:

```
result.put("imageUrl",downloadUri.toString());
```

In this way, your first child won't be added as:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- Users
        |
        --- Pp3Cc... smV2
              |
              --- Pp3Cc... smV2: "https://" //Incorrect
              |
              --- email: "test@gmail.com"
              |
              --- fullname: "Test"
```

But as:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- Users
        |
        --- Pp3Cc... smV2
              |
              --- imageUrl: "https://" //Correct
              |
              --- email: "test@gmail.com"
              |
              --- fullname: "Test"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use setValue to set the value to your realtime database.
The current method which you are using replace the completed data under userId, but if you wish to update a specific field, you should

```
root.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user)
```

use something like this.

Comment: i already use setValue(model) and it also deleted the existing data